# how to create a custom desktop session for x2go

Tags: x11, xorg, remote-desktop, x2go

I use the emacs window manager EXWM on my remote computer whith
lightdm. How can I create a session for emacs EXWM?
I am using the x2goclient. I have tried custom desktop with the
command "startx" and "/etc/x2go/xsession", I have also tried to run a
single application session with path to .xinitrc.

My xinitrc has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xhost +
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs
```

Please give me some advice on how to get this working.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If so please post the answer as I have the same issue.